# How to assign value for a class array object?

Tags: java, arrays, class

I am modifying a program, and it has `Class[] paramTypes` to store the input type. Then my question is how can I assign value for each cell of the array?
I can do this `paramTypes = new Class[]{int.class,double.class,String.class}` to assign for the paramTypes, but when I try to assign each cell in for loop like `paramTypes[i] = int.class`, it shows NullPointerException. So how shoud I do this in for loop?

This is the method:

```
    public MethodCall(String className,
        String methodName,
        Class[] paramTypes,
        Object[] params) {
    this.className = className;
    this.methodName = methodName;
    this.paramTypes = paramTypes;
    this.params = params;
}
```

This is instance:

```
MethodCall methodCall = new MethodCall("Foo", "bar", new Class[]{int.class,double.class},new Object[]{new Integer(10), new Double(123.0)});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize the array first.

```
paramTypes = new Class[4]; // or some other number
for(...){
  paramTypes[i] = int.class;
}
```

Comment: Can I initialize the array dynamically? Because I do not know the input length.

Comment: You mean you have the size in a variable? Yes u can. Why dont you give it a try!